# "Value already exists as a correcting value" error when cleansing data with DQS

Tags: sql-server, data-quality-services

In SQL Server 2012 Data Quality Services,  I need to clean the data in Term Based Relation as follows:

> **String       Replaceto****
>
> Wal               walmart**
>
> Wlr          walmart**
>
> Wlt         walmart**
>
> Walmart

That is the words "wal","wlr", and "wlt" have to be replaced with "walmart" and finally "walmart" is replaced with a empty space.

it shows the error as

```
SQL Server Data Quality Services
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2/1/2013 2:48:37 PM
Message Id: DataValueServiceTermBasedRelationCorrectedValueAlreadyCorrectingValue
Term Based Relation (walmart, ) cannot be added for domain 'keywordphrase' because 'walmart' value already exists as a correcting value.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft.Ssdqs.DataValueService.Service.DataValueServiceException: Term Based Relation (walmart, ) cannot be added for domain 'keywordphrase' because 'walmart' value already exists as a correcting value.
   at Microsoft.Ssdqs.DataValueService.Managers.DomainTermBasedRelationManager.PreapareAndValidateRelation(DomainTermBasedRelation relation, IMasterContext context)
   at Microsoft.Ssdqs.DataValueService.Managers.DomainTermBasedRelationManager.Add(IMasterContext context, ServiceDefinitionBase data)
   at Microsoft.Ssdqs.DataValueService.Service.DataValueServiceConcrete.Add(IMasterContext context, ReadOnlyCollection`1 data)
```

any suggestions for the solution
Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

It is my understanding that DQS does not support multi-level replacements (i.e, a->b then b->c).  Why not go straight to blanks for the firts three terms?